# Trouble getting attiny85 to drive nRF24l01+

Tags: attiny, nrf24l01, attiny85

I'm attempting to make an nRF24l01+ send out a simple identifying code when a button is pressed. I'm trying to keep the solution as small as possible, so I want to use the attiny85 to drive it.

Her's what I have working so far:

- I was able drive two nrf24l01+'s using a couple of raspberry pis, sending/receiving using node.js
- I was able to flash a basic "blinky" program to my attiny85 via raspberry pi and avrdude

I'm now attempting to flash the attiny85 with [this C code](https://gist.github.com/bendavis78/2a4b73fa6acc5d1f19631cf516fd6fe9) (I've also documented the wiring to the nRF in the linked file). But, I'm not picking anything up on the receiving nRF (which is still hooked up to the raspberry pi I used to test earlier). [Here's the nodejs code for the listening side](https://gist.github.com/bendavis78/577e3e870d65e4d01498ea8bb49ec59f).

Any suggestions on how to debug this? This is my first attempt at programming an AVR microcontroller.

Comment: Do you have the equipment to check the signals using a logic analyzer and/or to use [debugWIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DebugWIRE) (note that this would limit you to "high voltage serial programming")? See the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: In the Attiny85 you have  `bit 2="1": set CRC to 2-byte` but the listener.js has `const CRC_BYTES = 1;`.

Comment: @try-catch-finally the most I have with regard to equipment is a voltmeter. Not quite to the point where I'm ready to buy an oscilloscope. Is there a way to use debugWIRE with linux, or does it require some proprietary debugger?

Comment: @BruceAbbott nice catch! unfortunately, changing CRC_BYTES to 2 on the server didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I should also mention, my fuses on the attiny85 are as such: `efuse: 0xff (11111111)`, 
`hfuse: 0xdf (11011111)`, 
`lfuse: 0x62 (01100010)`